# line breaks in Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$("textarea").blur(function() {
  $("div").html($("textarea").val());
});

$("textarea").blur();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<textarea>test123123123123123123123123123123 teateafsdsafsdafaasdf</textarea>
```

I would like the content in the Div to appear to be exactly the same as in the textarea (line breaks instead of showing all in one line).

I've tried to set the height and width but that gives me a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: add parent div and for text area and for child div use width: 100%

Comment: Specify width of a div element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use word-break:break-all and give some width to the div it should work
check this snippet

```js
$("textarea").blur(function() {
  $("div").html($("textarea").val());
});

$("textarea").blur();
```

```css
div,textarea{
  word-break:break-all;
  width:220px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<textarea>test123123123123123123123123123123 teateafsdsafsdafaasdf</textarea>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For completeness, you may want to apply the CSS to both the `textarea` and `div` (ie `div, textarea { ... }`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `word-break: break-word;` on `<div>`.

Look at the snippet below:

```js
$("textarea").blur(function() {
  $("div").html($("textarea").val());
});

$("textarea").blur();
```

```css
div {
  width: 141px;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<textarea>test123123123123123123123123123123 teateafsdsafsdafaasdf</textarea>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("textarea").blur(function() {
  $("div").html($("textarea").val());
});

$("textarea").blur();
```

```css
div {
  width: 141px;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<textarea>test123123123123123123123123123123 teateafsdsafsdafaasdf</textarea>
```

This comes close to being the same as the textarea. You could use height in combination with overflow: hidden on the div to limit the height.

the word-break: break-all breaks the line in between any two letters

Answer (score 1):

> Try this for a 'cross-browser' solution.

```
 div {
        width: 220px;
        -ms-word-break: break-all;
        word-break: break-all;
        -webkit-hyphens: auto;
        -moz-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("textarea").blur(function() {
  $("div").html($("textarea").val());
});

$("textarea").blur();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<textarea>test123123123123123123123123123123 &#13;&#10;teateafsdsafsdafaasdf</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to space letters or they won't break into a new line.

```js
$("textarea").blur(function() {
  $("div").html($("textarea").val());
});

$("textarea").blur();
```

```css
div{width:200px}
textarea{width:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<textarea>t e s t 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show line breaks, you can use a `<pre>` tag. this is for pre-formatted text like you have.

```js
function copy(){
    $("pre").html($("textarea").val());  
}

$("textarea").on('input',copy);
copy()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>

<textarea cols="80">test123123123123123123123123123123 teateafsdsafsdafaasdf</textarea>
```